# Android button not responding to click event/

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

As far as I can tell, everything needed for a button to respond is in place. Im baffled so would appreciate a pair of extra eyes on this.

Simple homepage activity, login or create a profile buttons displayed. Click the login button and the next activity ***should*** display. Application runs on device but buttons do not respond.

Code

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button login;
    Button createProfile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        login           = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        login.setOnClickListener(this);

        createProfile   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createProfileButton);
        createProfile.setOnClickListener(this);         
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent;
        switch(view.getId()){

          case R.id.loginButton: /** Start a new Activity LoginActivity.java */
              intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
              this.startActivity(intent);
              break;

          case R.id.createProfileButton: /** Start a new Activity About.java */
              //intent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
              //this.startActivity(intent);
              break;
          } 
    }
}
```

HomeScreen layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="51dp"
    android:text="Login" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/createProfileButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/loginButton"
    android:text="createProfile" />
```

Login Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is the login page!" />
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.nutrtionintuition"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nutrtionintuition.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

LoginACtivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this whole content of `onClick()` method? Because currently your `onClick()` method do nothing. Only defines intent and switch.

Comment: make sure the clickable property is not set to false in the xml.

Comment: How do you know it's not called? BTW, learn how to use the debugger. These are simple bugs to work out with the debugger. Trying to code without a debugger is like building a car with only one spanner. Not using the debugger is making things harder for you. Debuggers save an enormous amount of time and make everything easier. The debugger will find gold in your garden and unicorns in the car park. Writing Android Java code without using the debugger will cause your teeth to turn blue and your knees to change places with your elbows. Debugging aids digestion and keeps your breath sweet. :)

Comment: @sayed no clickable properties are set in the xml

Comment: @Geralt, are you sure? Because its pretty clear the startActivity method is called..

Comment: @simon, ok, well the next activity is not displayed, which should be the flow..

Comment: So either the onCLick is not called, **or** the Activity is not displayed.  Put a breakpoint on the first line of the onClick.  Is it hit?

Comment: Paste your xml code for this activity and the second activity class and xml and manifest so that we can get a better picture. Maybe something is wrong in these files. The code you pasted is ok. Paste the rest

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. post your xml files. I am pretty sure there is something wrong with your xml

Comment: Your code is OK. Have you included all the activities in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: New code segments added, which as far as I am aware are correct.

Comment: I feel like there's something you're not telling us. This all seems good to me. I even ran this on my own phone and it works.

Comment: post your code for your `LoginActivity` class

Comment: strange. well, im running a htc one if that makes any difference..

Comment: LoginAvtivity class is now added

Comment: @user3052839 check out my answer. Please accept it if it works for you. You are also inflating the same menu, so that could be a future problem for you. Change the layout in each class and you should see that it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *both* classes (`HomeActivity` and `LoginActivity`), you set the content view like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

Your code is working, but the new activity is loading the same layout.

---

Change

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);` 

to 

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);`

(or whatever your login layout is named) in your `LoginActivity` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK and it must work. It seems that your activites are not included in your AndroidManifest.xml.

If so, maybe you are actually launching your another activity, but you may have missed to put the right layout id in the `setContentView` function.

Comment: in that case it would have thrown a ClassNotFoundException